# How to display copies of images captured by OpenCV VideoCapture correctly?

Tags: opencv, c++11, image-processing, png, video-capture

I am trying to use the OpenCV VideoCapture class to read images sequentially from a specific folder, as shown in the code below, which is extracted from https://www.kevinhughes.ca/tutorials/reading-image-sequences-with-opencv.
 The reading works just fine and I can view the video streaming of the read images (imgSrc) correctly. The problem happens when I try to copy each frame into a new Mat object using nested for loops, the new image (imgDst) is different from the original one. I attached the results of the frame below. Is there anything I am doing wrong so that I get this weird result?

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

void help(char** argv)
{
cout << "\nThis program gets you started reading a sequence of images using cv::VideoCapture.\n"
     << "Image sequences are a common way to distribute video data sets for computer vision.\n"
     << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " <path to the first image in the sequence>\n"
     << "example: " << argv[0] << " right%%02d.jpg\n"
     << "q,Q,esc -- quit\n"
     << "\tThis is a starter sample, to get you up and going in a copy paste fashion\n"
     << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
if(argc != 2)
{
  help(argv);
  return 1;
}

string arg = argv[1];
VideoCapture sequence(arg);
if (!sequence.isOpened())
{
  cerr << "Failed to open Image Sequence!\n" << endl;
  return 1;
}

Mat imgSrc; // source image
for(;;)
{
  sequence >> imgSrc;

if(imgSrc.empty())
  {
      cout << "End of Sequence" << endl;
      break;
  }
  Mat imgDst = cv::Mat::zeros(cv::Size(imgSrc.size().width,imgSrc.size().height),CV_16U);


  // Copying the elements of imgSrc to imgDst
  uint16_t* imgSrcPtr;
  uint16_t* imgDstPtr;
  for(int i = 0; i < imgSrc.rows; i++)
  {
      imgDstPtr = imgDst.ptr<uint16_t>(i);
      imgSrcPtr = imgSrc.ptr<uint16_t>(i);

       for(int j= 0; j < imgSrc.cols; j++)
       imgDstPtr[j] = imgSrcPtr[j];
  }

  namedWindow("Source image ",WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );

  namedWindow("Destination image ",WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
  imshow("Destination image ", imgDst);
  waitKey(0;

return 0;
}
```

[image: Source image]
   [image: Destination image]

Comment: `Mat imgDst = imgSrc.clone();` and you're assuming uint16, which is rarely the case

Comment: image.clone() is not an option for me, I need to copy the image on a pixel-by-pixel basis. I have png images of 16 bit depth value, which types should I assume ? Is there anything wrong with loop and pointers I am using ?

Comment: This looks like an xy problem. 1) Why can't you use `clone`? 2) Can't you just read the images 16bit? 3) Why do you need to copy pixel-by-pixel? Why do you need a copy of the original image?

Comment: I don't see where my mistake is from xy perspective. 1) This is not the purpose, I'm making new version of the image just to check that I'm accessing the images read by the VideoCapture class correctly 2) I didn't get your point here 3) I need the reading to be pixel-by-pixel due to performance-related issues.

Answer (score 0):

Using image.type(), I have found that the VideoCapture class is converting the grayscale read frames CV_16U to CV_8UC3 (RGB24) format, therefore a simple color space conversion to grayscale solved the problem.